# Converting input polygon to GeoDataFrame in Python

Tags: python, pyqgis, geopandas, convert, geodataframe

I am in the process of developing a plugin for QGIS and I need to convert an input vector layer (containing a polygon) into `GeoDataFrame`. The input layer is imported like this:

```
input_Area = self.dlg.ui.Area.currentLayer()
```

And I need to use it for the following function (which uses a GeoDataFrame as input):

```py
def create_grid_from_polygon(polygon, grid_size):
    polygon_geom = polygon['geometry']
    bbox = polygon_geom.bounds
    xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax = bbox.minx[0], bbox.miny[0], bbox.maxx[0], bbox.maxy[0]
    #Calculate number of rows and columns
    row = int((ymax-ymin) / grid_size)
    col = int((xmax-xmin) / grid_size)

    #initialize point grid
    grid_layer = []

    for i in range(row):
        for j in range(col):
            #Calculate x and y coordinates of the current point
            x = xmin + j * grid_size
            y = ymin + i * grid_size

            #Create a QgsPointXY object for point
            point = QgsPointXY(x,y)

            #Check if it is within the polygon and add the points within the area
            if polygon.contains(point):
                grid_layer.append(point)
    
    return grid_layer
```

I have been trying something like this:

```py
features = []
for feature in input_Area.getFeatures():
    features.append(feature)

geometry_col = input_Area.geometry.name()
if geometry_col:
    gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(features, geometry=geometry_col)
else:
    print("Geometry column not found")
```

But I can't really get it to work. It seems to be having trouble finding the name of the geometry column, and here it is important to note that since the code is for a plugin, the code needs to find this name on its own.

If this method isn't possible I'd love any suggestions for another solution.

Comment: You can use geopandas

Answer (score 2):

GeoPandas can create the GeoDataFrame instance directly from the QGIS features iterator, using the [`from_features()`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.from_features.html) class method. It will correctly recognize the attributes and geometry.

All you need to do is:

```py
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(input_Area.getFeatures())
```